# cannot run a simple java class

Tags: java

I created a simple java class:

```
package com.name;

public class Main {
    public static void main (String [] args) {
        System.out.println("I have made it");   
    }
}
```

and save it in Main.java

Then I did java Main.java, and I can see the Main.class

I tried to run it as:

```
java Main

java com.name.Main
```

but I kept getting:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class Main
```

My java -version output is:

```
java version "1.8.0_191"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_191-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.191-b12, mixed mode)
```

and my $JAVA_HOME environment variable is:

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_191.jdk/Contents/Home
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your class is in the `com.name` package, so the class loader expects to find it in a `com/name` subdirectory:

```
mkdir -p com/name
mv Main.class com/name
java com.name.Main
```

Comment: The question and response don't mention the compilation step. It might be worthwhile to include that, since it's how the class file was created in the top directory to begin with. Set the classpath right and compile + execute from the root directory, not the subdirectory.